# How to get count of single and multiple matches in a single SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume I have following 2 tables,

```
table1
-----------
col1 | col2
-----------
a1      b1
a2      b2
a3      b2
a4      b4
a1      b1

table2
-----------
col1 | col2
-----------
a1      b1
a2      b3
a2      b2
a4      b4
```

In the above example, there is one record in table2 (a1,b1) which appears more than once in table1(2 in this case) and two records in table2((a2,b2) and (a4,b4)) that appears exactly once in table1. I want number of records in table2 that has exact one match in table 1 and number of records in table2 that has more than 1 match in table1. How do I get this result in a single query. Something like below:-

### countOfSingleMatch | countOfMultipleMatch

```
    2                    1
```

I could do it with separate queries but I wanted to achieve this in a single query.

Comment: Show the separate queries for each of the numbers.  The question is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want conceptually is a tally of the number of times a record in `table2` matches to another record in `table1`.  Since you don't need to report the number of a times a match does *not* take place, we can start off by considering an `INNER JOIN` between the two tables.  Then, we can aggregate by `col1` and `col2` and count the number of matches.  Finally, pass over this as a subquery and count the number of times each type of match happens.

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.cnt = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countOfSingleMatch,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.cnt > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countOfMultipleMatch
FROM
(
    SELECT t2.col1, t2.col2, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM table2 t2
    INNER JOIN table1 t1
        ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
    GROUP BY t2.col1, t2.col2
) t
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: @OtoShavadze I'd prefer to use `> 1`, but yes I answered so quickly my initial answer had some rough edges.  Gordon is awake; do you really blame me here?

Comment: Wait... Gordon sleeps?

Comment: @SqlZim LOL...he works at Columbia, I know roughly what hours he should be awake in the NYC time zone...but then again you never know...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - lol, no, there is acceptable some  typos in situations like this ))

Comment: @SqlZim - Enlightening the SQL world all day everyday ;)

Comment: Awesome. @Tim Biegeleisen  Thanks for the quick answer, it worked for me.